# Strip off string parts by a pattern R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a variable called `summed_EU_Sales`, I want to get `EU` only.

I have tried to do it using `gsub` this way:

```
gsub(".*summed_", "", summed_EU_Sales)
```

which only removes the first `summed_`. I struggle to remove both of the sides.

Comment: You may want to re-phrase your question, "_Remove everything before and after string_" sounds like you already know the string you'd like to keep, though most likely you want to strip off some parts matching a pattern. Or split input by underscore and extract 2nd item (`unlist(strsplit("summed_EU_Sales","_"))[2]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variable name `summed_EU_Sales` is actually a string `"summed_EU_Sales"`, we can use regex groupings:

```r
sub(".*_(EU)_.*", "\\1", "summed_EU_Sales")
#> [1] "EU"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
x<-cbind.data.frame("summed_EU_Sales"=c(1:5),
                    "summed_jap_Sales"=c(1:5))
names(x) <- str_match(names(x), "_\\s*(.*?)\\s*_")[,2]
```